# scale_fill_manual() issue in ggplot coefficient plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to be able to differentiate between the model with controls and the model without. I specified in `scale_fill_manual` that I want "Controls" to be red and "No controls" to be blue. Unfortunately, the lines in the legend continue to be black. This is the following code I have:

```
# packages
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)

# list models
models <- list(
  "No controls" = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars),
  "Controls" = lm(mpg ~ wt + hp + qsec, data = mtcars)
)

# define variables
cm <- c('wt' = 'Weight',
        'hp' = 'Horsepower',
        'qsec' = 'Quarter Mile Time')

# combine all coefficients from models
coef_data <- data.frame()
for (model_name in names(models)) {
  model <- models[[model_name]]
  tidy_df <- tidy(model)
  tidy_df$model <- model_name
  coef_data <- rbind(coef_data, tidy_df)
}

# filter to only show cm variables
coef_data <- coef_data[coef_data$term %in% names(cm), ]

# create levels
coef_data$model <- factor(coef_data$model, levels = c("Controls", "No controls"))

# create ggplot
p <- ggplot(coef_data, aes(x = term, y = estimate, ymin = estimate - 1.96 * std.error, ymax = estimate + 1.96 * std.error, fill = model)) +
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Controls" = "red", "No controls" = "blue")) +  # Specify colors for each model type
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Variable", y = "Estimate", fill = "Model")

p
```

Answer (score 0):

In `geom_pointrange()` we have to separately define the `fill` (points) and `color` (lines) aesthetics:

```
p <- ggplot(coef_data, aes(x = term, y = estimate, ymin = estimate - 1.96 * std.error, ymax = estimate + 1.96 * std.error, fill = model, color = model)) +
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Controls" = "red", "No controls" = "blue")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Controls" = "red", "No controls" = "blue")) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Variable", y = "Estimate", fill = "Model", color = "Model")

p
```

[image]